# Merge Angular 5 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, angular5

I am being involved in an ASP.NET project where I used Angular 5 for front-end development. Now the development on front-end is over and being focused on the back-end. Can someone guide me **how to merge Angular 5 on VS 2013** so that when I build the solution and run it, I will **get my front-end rather than getting the default home page of AS.NET**. I am fairly new to AS.NET and as well as to Angular 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try build empty web application that contains your angular application, but tbh it's much more comfortable to keep it separated. Create solution for API application and use VS for it. Additionaly use eg. visual studio code to develop frontend. This is way how I work with this set.

Comment: Exactly the same I have already done! What I now want to know whether there is any mechanism to merge my coding in Visual Studio Code into Visual Studio 2013 so that I will get my designed front-end when I build and run VS.

Comment: I think it looks promising in your case
[link]https://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-use-angular4-wth-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: It seems that I need to create a MVC project. but can you tell me what if I have created a WebAPI ASP.NET project?

Comment: IMHO it's better to keep it separated and run two instances from different environmants, and follow REST principals. This is most common way to work with angular application (even in most of SPA frameworks).